# CSS fake CRT effect not covering page height

Tags: css

I've found a great [fake CRT effect](http://aleclownes.com/2017/02/01/crt-display.html) that uses pure CSS to mimic those old monitor scan-lines. Unfortunately while it covers the full width of the page, it only applies itself to the height of the initially loaded page; any content that you have to scroll down to view is not covered. I've tried altering the background-size element but all my attempts either do nothing or break things.

CSS here:

```
@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.27861;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.34769;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0.23604;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 0.90626;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0.18128;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.83891;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0.65583;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 0.67807;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.26559;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0.84693;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.96019;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0.08594;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.20313;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0.71988;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0.53455;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.37288;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.71428;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 0.70419;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0.7003;
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0.36108;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.24387;
  }
}
@keyframes textShadow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0.4389924193300864px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.4389924193300864px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  5% {
    text-shadow: 2.7928974010788217px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.7928974010788217px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  10% {
    text-shadow: 0.02956275843481219px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.02956275843481219px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 0.40218538552878136px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.40218538552878136px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  20% {
    text-shadow: 3.4794037899852017px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -3.4794037899852017px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: 1.6125630401149584px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -1.6125630401149584px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 0.7015590085143956px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.7015590085143956px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  35% {
    text-shadow: 3.896914047650351px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -3.896914047650351px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  40% {
    text-shadow: 3.870905614848819px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -3.870905614848819px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  45% {
    text-shadow: 2.231056963361899px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.231056963361899px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0.08084290417898504px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.08084290417898504px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  55% {
    text-shadow: 2.3758461067427543px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.3758461067427543px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  60% {
    text-shadow: 2.202193051050636px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.202193051050636px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  65% {
    text-shadow: 2.8638780614874975px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.8638780614874975px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  70% {
    text-shadow: 0.48874025155497314px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.48874025155497314px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow: 1.8948491305757957px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -1.8948491305757957px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  80% {
    text-shadow: 0.0833037308038857px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.0833037308038857px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  85% {
    text-shadow: 0.09769827255241735px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -0.09769827255241735px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  90% {
    text-shadow: 3.443339761481782px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -3.443339761481782px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  95% {
    text-shadow: 2.1841838852799786px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.1841838852799786px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 2.6208764473832513px 0 1px rgba(0, 30, 255, 0.5),
      -2.6208764473832513px 0 1px rgba(255, 0, 80, 0.3), 0 0 3px;
  }
}
.crt::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(18, 16, 16, 0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: flicker 0.15s infinite;
}
.crt::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(18, 16, 16, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 50%),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.06),
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.02),
      rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.06)
    );
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100% 2px, 3px 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.crt {
  animation: textShadow 1.6s infinite;
}
```

You can view the code in action [on my portfolio page](https://theamberlamps.github.io/pro_portfolio/). Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick fix, on your `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`, which I'd explain why but I get the feeling since you basically just linked your site that's filled with other folks work that you're more interested in just a quick fix...

Comment: I'm sorry, my portfolio is filled with other people's work? What are you talking about?

I'm not opposed to a "quick fix" as you call it, but I'd certainly like to understand *why* it's a fix. CSS isn't my strong suit, and this page is by far my most ambitious undertaking in that regard.

Comment: Sorry re-reading that comment it didn't sound as rude before so apologies there. I meant more in the case of the [glowing nodes](https://codepen.io/pawelqcm/pen/oxPYox) and the crt effects etc. Anyway it's a fix that gets the job done since it's a class attached to the body and will just consume the viewport. Semantically though the way you have the canvas fixing a height and relying on a DOM structure like that will cause you some other headaches as you go, like the white space under your "work" section etc. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your responses, fixed positioning works like a charm. I have to say I'm somewhat confused as to why absolute positioning didn't work, because the CRT class is assigned to the body element which has no ancestors.

Comment: `absolute` is *relative* to the parent, which is unreliable here since there is not a relative positioned parent in this case because it's on the body and the body by default has a size dictated by the content, while `fixed` is relying on the html document window/viewport itself. So you've now detached it from that DOM flow we just talked about being possibly not ideal, and **fixed** it to the highest point in the DOM so it will consume the window size instead of a relational parent. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Chris W.'s suggestion works like a charm, fixed positioning causes the CRT effect to cover the entirety of the body element.